# The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format at IMAP implementation

Tags: c#, winforms, email, imap, imapclient

I have tried to read my mail inbox through c# code and it has given an error "the handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format".

Here is my code,

```
   using AE.Net.Mail;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace MailApp
   {
   class Program
   {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {

         try
         {
             ImapClient ic = new ImapClient("mail.topformtechnologies.com", "username@topformtechnologies.com", "password", AuthMethods.Login, 143, true);

            // Select a mailbox. Case-insensitive
            ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
            Console.WriteLine(ic.GetMessageCount());
            Console.ReadLine();
            // Get the first *11* messages. 0 is the first message;
            // and it also includes the 10th message, which is really the eleventh ;)
            // MailMessage represents, well, a message in your mailbox
            MailMessage[] mm = ic.GetMessages(0, 10);
            foreach (MailMessage m in mm)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Body);
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
                ////            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is detailed error:

System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost)
   at AE.Net.Mail.TextClient.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port, Boolean ssl, RemoteCertificateValidationCallback validateCertificate) in c:\Repos\aenetmail\TextClient.cs:line 87
   at AE.Net.Mail.TextClient.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port, Boolean ssl, Boolean skipSslValidation) in c:\Repos\aenetmail\TextClient.cs:line 59
   at AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient..ctor(String host, String username, String password, AuthMethods method, Int32 port, Boolean secure, Boolean skipSslValidation) in c:\Repos\aenetmail\ImapClient.cs:line 35
   at BulkEmail.CreateSignature.btnFont_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\TFTLap2\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BulkEmail\BulkEmail\CreateSignature.cs:line 24

Please someone guide me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you did not mean port 993, the ssl IMAP port?

Comment: 143 is open there, and it's a plain Dovecot server. What's the exception, then? I mean in detail?

Comment: yes its 143, I checked my email server configuration of my cpanel.

Comment: You either need starttls or to turn off ssl.  You are trying to connect ssl to a unencrypted port

Comment: I even tried by making ssl false, still no help.....:(

Comment: As @Max and @arnt have mentioned, the exception you got is from SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient() due to the fact that you are connecting to a plain-text IMAP server and the SslStream expects to negotiate an SSL connection with an SSL-encrypted IMAP server. If you are still having problems even after changing the `useSsl` argument to `false`, then you must be getting a different error. What is that new error?